# Simple Cocoa application with MenuBar Icon. How To:?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, macos

I'm trying to make a Cocoa application that's pretty simple.  I have three windows with three messages on them, that's all there is to it.  What I'm trying to do is this:

The user runs the app, the app icon appears in the menu bar and that's all that happens, no menu and no dock icon

Then, the user can click the MenuBar Icon and have a dropdown list and choose from the three available messages.

I know it's useless, but this is literally my first application and I can't figure out how to get NSStatusItem to work properly...

I've looked around and found some tutorials but I can't seem to follow any of them...any help?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. Regarding the "no dock icon" - add boolean `LSUIElement` entry to Info.plist file and set it to **true**. This won't show application in app switcher UI (cmd+tab) as well.
2. Adding menu bar icon is as much as looking into `NSStatusBar` and `NSStatusItem` documentation and using example code there:

.

```
// this one is taken from apple documentation
- (void)activateStatusMenu {
    NSStatusBar *bar = [NSStatusBar systemStatusBar];

    theItem = [bar statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
    [theItem retain];

    [theItem setTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"Tablet",@"")];
    [theItem setHighlightMode:YES];
    [theItem setMenu:theMenu];
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    [self activateStatusMenu];
}
```

**Update** Since ARC does not allow `retain` calls in the code, I managed to solve the issue by creating `theItem` as `__strong` instance variable of the class where the item is being created.

Comment: Wow that's great.  I (as my handle implies) am a total cocoa newb and I'm coming over from a vb.net background and am struggling a little with the objective-c syntax and what not.  I am however finding that the apple cocoa documentation is a lot more thorough than the microsoft vb docs, which aren't very "user friendly".  Your answer helped quite a bit, and I thank you for your assistance.